# Sum a 3d numpy array for the third dimension only

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I need the code in python
for example i have a numpy array sized (x,y,z)
i want to sum it into an array of (x,y), sum z only
z was an array of number, after sum he become a number to finaly get a 2d matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the axis on which the sum will be performed for the numpy function sum:

```py
import numpy as np

res = np.sum(arr, axis=2)
# np.sum(arr, axis=-1) is equivalent in this case
```